# Django Queryset mock objects and count

Tags: python, django, mocking, django-queryset

I am looking for a way to mock both the Django queryset result and the count result in the same test.
Please find below a code snippet to give an overview of what I try to do. This is not the real code, just a simplified version that does nothing interesting.

```
# METHOD 
def method_to_mock(car_ids):
    cars = Car.objects.filter(id__in=car_ids).order_by("creation_date")
    if cars.count() != len(car_ids):
        missing_cars = set(car_ids) - set(cars.values_list("id", flat=True))
        logger.error(f"Failed to retrieve cars {missing_cars}.")

    for car in cars:
        print(car.brand)

# TESTING
mock_filter = mocker.patch("Car.objects")
mock_filter.filter.return_value.order_by.return_value = [mocker.Mock(), mocker.Mock()]
mock_filter.filter.return_value.order_by.return_value.count.return_value = 2
method_to_mock([0, 1, 2])
```

This does not work as the list of mocks do not have a count method. I don't want to return a Mock instead of the list of Mock as I still want to be able to loop through the mocks.

Could you please help on that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following way to do it using `__iter__`

```
mock_filter = mocker.patch("Car.objects.filter")
mock_filter.return_value.order_by.return_value = mock_filter
mock_filter.__iter__.return_value = [mocker.Mock(), mocker.Mock()]
mock_filter.count.return_value = 2
```